# How to create a pre-signed POST URL using AWS SDK for Go

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-sdk-go

How can I create pre-signed **POST** (not PUT) URLs using the AWS SDK for Go?

The SDK for JavaScript has a method [`s3.createPresignedPost`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#createPresignedPost-property) for it, but I can't find a similar operation in the SDK for Go.

```js
var params = {
  Bucket: 'bucket',
  Fields: {
    key: 'key'
  }
};
s3.createPresignedPost(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) {
    console.error('Presigning post data encountered an error', err);
  } else {
    console.log('The post data is', data);
  }
});
```

How can I create and sign a URL with a [POST policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-HTTPPOSTConstructPolicy.html) using the AWS SDK for Go?

Comment: In the SDK Ver 2 there is an example with presigned scenario. See the [doc, clicking here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-library/latest/ug/go_2_s3_code_examples.html)

Answer (score 1):

Browser based presigned post feature is currently missing from AWS Go SDK, more details can be found [here](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/issues/666).

[This](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/issues/370) might also be useful.